# Ios Adding Value in loop in sqlite

Tags: ios

Hey my code is very simple , i have crated a sqlite table with one column id and message.
my sqlite table is created successfully. i want to insert 5 string value in message column .my code for insert string value

```
  - (IBAction)addTextToDatabase:(id)sender
  {
     sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
     const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

     if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE (MESSAGE) VALUES (\"%@\")",
                                self.textField.text];

          const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
          for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
             sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, insert_stmt,
                                -1, &statement, NULL);


              sqlite3_finalize(statement);
          }
          //  sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, insert_stmt,
          //                -1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
              statusOfAddingToDB = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text added -- %@",
             textField.text];
          } else {
            statusOfAddingToDB = @"Failed to add contact";
          }

          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DB Status"
           message:statusOfAddingToDB delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"   
            otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

      //        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
         sqlite3_close(myDatabase);
     }
    }
```

but when i check my database only one value is added to it.please help how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write sqlite3_step statement within for loop before sqlite3_finalize statement

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this statement:

sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE

after each insertion.